# HTML5 executing query without postback

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, postback

I am using html5, javascript and JSP for my project. I want to know if there is some method that i can used to execute a query from my servlet without actually posting back the page. i know it can be done in ASP.net but i do n't how it can be be done in java script and JSP. Actually i have a dynamic webpage displaying data from server.what i want is that in a click event of button i want to execute a query form server and update it on the page. i know i can submit the form but it will submit the page which i want to avoid.Any suggestion......
regards
nquazi

Comment: you're possibly looking for Ajax? Please format your text better

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX request to submit inputs and get back an output without reloading that page.  Here is a previous stackoverflow answer that shows you how to do a HTTP GET request.

[HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

You will then need to process your inputs, run the query, and send back an output on the backend server.